# How do you add the snap store to Synaptic?

Tags: package-management, downloads, snap

When I search in Synaptic for snaps that I know exist, they do not show up. How do you add the snap store to the repositories in Synatpic?

Comment: You can't and likely never will be able to as synaptic has  no snap support & it's development is pretty much nil

Answer (score 2):

You can't, today, do this.

Somebody would have to extend synaptic to talk to snapd, either directly or using snapd-glib. While relatively straightforward (and nearly everything the `snap` tool does is by talking to `snapd`), it is quite a lot of work, especially if (as I imagine is the case) synaptic has not been thought from the start to talk to multiple packaging backends.

Given that synaptic has seen no work in two years, and that the project maintainer is a very active snapd developer, I suspect development on it has stopped.